# Ubuntu 12.04 Apache 2 - Inline CSS working but external CSS not working

Tags: apache2, php, html, css

In installed apache2 for use as a development server. Created my site, and it loads correctly in my browser, except that...

External CSS stylesheets don't load. Inline CSS works, and the `style` tag works, but   `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"` doesn't seem to do anything.

My apache2.conf is unedited. Here are my php5.conf file and my site conf file, in case they are needed:

mods-enabled/php5.conf

> ```
> <IfModule mod_php5.c>
>     <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
>   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
>     </FilesMatch>
>     <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
>   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
>     </FilesMatch>
>     <FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
>         SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
>     </FilesMatch>
>     <FilesMatch ".+\.htm$">
>         SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
>     </FilesMatch>
>     <FilesMatch ".+\.xhtml$">
>         SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
>     </FilesMatch>
>     # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
>     # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
>     # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
>     <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
>         <Directory /home/*/public_html>
>             php_admin_value engine Off
>         </Directory>
>     </IfModule>
> </IfModule>
> ```

sites-enables/au.camarillo.conf

> ```
> NameVirtualHost au.camarillo
> <VirtualHost au.camarillo>
> ServerAdmin daniel@camarillo
> #we want to be able to access the web site using www.au.camarillo or au.camarillo
> ServerAlias www.au.camarillo
> DocumentRoot /home/daniel/sites/au
> #we want specific log file for this server
> CustomLog /var/log/apache2/au.camarillo-access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I also had faced the same problem but I got a solution. The solution is:

```
<link href="./css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Note that the "." before "/css" is indicating the current working directory on Ubuntu. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a derp. I figured it out. Turns out it was a page-specific problem, not a server problem.

Here's the code for my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
...some content...
</div>

<div id="phpinfo">
<?php include('info.php') ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code for info.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

When the include in my HTML page is commented out, the stylesheet loads as expected. A quick glance at the source code for info.php reveals

```
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}
```

Overriding the external stylesheet, but not any internal or inline style info.

Thanks for looking at my question.