# Apache 2.4.7 doesn't load all .css files

Tags: apache2, xampp

I run a server with Ubuntu and Apache 2.4.7 and for debugging I run locally XAMPP Version 5.6.19.

For the first time I noticed a difference in the page I'm developing. On the XAMPP Apache works everything as desired. On the Ubuntu server there is one issue: the Apache doesn't load one of two `.css` files. Everything is the SAME(folder structure, files etc..).

The .css files are stored in `/var/www/html/css/` on the ubuntu server and the `/var/www/html/index.html` file include both `.css` files via this two instructions located in the head of the html file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modalCustomization.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The file `/var/www/html/css/style.css` will be loaded correctly.
The file `/var/www/html/css/modalCustomization.css` will not be loaded.

Any suggestions why the Apache on the ubuntu server is doing/not doing that?

Comment: What happens if you put the `modalCustomization` entry above the main one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution from another [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/459011/529121). Everything works if I add a `./` before the path in `index.html`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/modalCustomization.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need mod_mime, and ensure you have these lines in your httpd.conf:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

[That should do it.source](https://serverfault.com/a/405231/183537)

EDIT

Make sure that this line is not commented

`IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf`

and the mine.conf and the load exists and the file

`/etc/mime.types` is exist

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem as yours, noticed that your 1st css uses lowercase and the 2nd propercase.

Was using "StyleSheet.css" but when I renamed as "styles.css" it suddenly works!
Running XAMPP on Windows 10.